# How to identify a google map marker on click?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cfml

I'm creating a Google Map from the developer API v3. It's populated with markers created dynamically from ColdFusion querying an MsSQL database.

```
 <cfloop query="One">
 <script>locations[<cfoutput>#One.userID#</cfoutput>
] = new google.maps.LatLng(<cfoutput>#One.latLng#</cfoutput>);
 </script>
 </cfloop>
```

I need a way to recognise the marker when its clicked so I can display address details in a box below the map and also higlight markers when a button is clicked lower on the page.

Comment: It might help to show us the JS you're using for adding markers too.  I'd add the markers to an array, which then makes them easy to access later

Comment: Probably nothing to do with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you would typically assign your own custom properties to the Marker. Something like:

```
function markerClicked(e) {
    console.log('Marker ' + marker.myData + ' has been clicked');
}
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(...);
marker.myData = 1; //this could be arbitrary data or even another object
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', markerClicked);
```

Adding custom data to any Google Maps API object has risks though. Google's code is obfuscated and the internal (non-documented) properties can and do change. Make sure your property is named in such a way that it won't conflict with any existing property or future property. Tip: Choose a property name longer than 3 letters.

If you are going to minify/compile/compress your maps code, then there are [additional considerations](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3821).

Answer (score 4):

What about :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
    var clicked = this;
    //...
});
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Comment: Fantastic! Combining this with Chad Killingsworth's idea of adding data (ie id) to the marker worked for me ... I'm looping through an array of places and adding a marker with accompanying InfoWindow for each ... then: `if (clicked.id == ...)`

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty thoroughly documented/explained in the documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

When you create markers, add dom listeners to the markers like this

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
```

Comment: Sure you have a reference to the marker being clicked, but if you are managing your own list of markers `[{ marker: marker1, data: '1'}, {marker: marker2, data:'2'}, ...]`, it doesn't help you look up your marker in the array without looping through the whole thing.